# Swift: TableViewController didSelectRowAt Index_path function is not work

Tags: json, uitableview, collectionview

have three controllers. in first `CollectionViewController`, next `TableViewController` and last one `CollectionViewController`. The first and second controller passed json perfectly. but in `tableViewController` did select is not working.

**first collectionViewController**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let controller1 = ListTableView()
        controller1.product_id = arrCategory[indexPath.item].id!
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)
}
```

**the second tableViewController**
**maybe the problem is here code**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let controller1 = DescriptionCollectionView(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        controller1.product_id = arrProduct[indexPath.item].id!
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)
}
```

**json web code is for 3 no collectionViewController**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use `prepareForSegue` for clear code, below the example :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier") {
        let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! YourSecondViewController //with UINavigationController as top view

        controller.valueFromSecondController = self.valueFromThisController
    }
}
```

Then in your `didSelect` function just call :

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier", sender: row)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: segue does not work in swift programmatically. i am doing all code programmatically here.

Comment: are you using programmaticaly segue?

Comment: there is segue in swift programmatically